# As a Swedish traveller travelling to the USA, what and when will I need to provide to prove that I'm fully vaccinated and tested?

Tags: usa, sweden, vaccinations, covid-19

I will be travelling from Sweden directly to the USA under the current travel restrictions. I understand that at the moment, this requires you to be fully vaccinated. What's not clear however is how I will prove that I am vaccinated and tested.

Is the PDF I get from https://covidbevis.se/vaccinationsbevis-web/ all I need to prove my vaccination status, or is there more to it? How does it work for testing? When will I need to show this proof, at the airport before boarding, or on arrival? Both?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Primary enforcement for vaccine and testing requirements when travelling to the US falls to the airline that is transporting you to the US.

The specific procedures will depend on the airline, but will generally involve them needing to see your vaccination/test results at either check-in or at the gate, as well as potentially a recommendation to upload the details in advance (generally not required, but can streamline the process at the airport).

Many airlines will include details of the exact process on their website, such as these for [Swiss](https://www.swiss.com/au/en/customer-support/travel-and-corona/faq-entering-usa), [Lufthansa](https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/faq-entering-us) and [British Airways](https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/incident/coronavirus/entry-requirements#).

You may also be required to show proof of vaccination/testing on arrival in the US, however this is not normally required as the airline will have confirmed the details to US immigration in advance.

Comment: Can confirm that previously the CBP didn’t  ask for test results on arrival, though of course it’s possible they sometimes cross checked it for some passengers.

Comment: @JonathanReez What is "the CBP"?

Comment: @Newbyte Customs and Border Protection I think

Comment: I can confirm I didn't have to prove my vaccination or testing status on arrival, only during check-in before flying. The airline said there would be people conducting random checks for Covid-19 tests in the airport, but I never saw anyone like that and I feel unsure how true that is given that domestic US flights don't require testing or vaccination.